# Missing characters on webpage

Tags: fonts

We recently launched a new website and two people from our office had the same issue which was there were missing letters. See the attachment below.
[image]

Both users were viewing it on Firefox and IE browsers which were up-to-date on PC and we are using Google Fonts.

**Additional Info:**
- When I checked the source code, the text is there. 
- I didn't see anything unusual when I check the network tabs or any other reports
- I am using Google font called 'Fira Sans'
- Most people in our office (160 people) don't see the issue. Only two people are having the same issue.

Comment: some more details? Is the text there in the source? How are you loading a font for this, and do the browser network tabs report anything odd? Does the console report any errors? What does the computed style information tell you about which font is *actually* being applied to stretches of text? etc

Answer (score 0):

I'd check the source (on the browser page, right click -> view source) to verify whether the raw HTML has effectively the missing characters in the fist place or not.

If they are missing, then investigate where the HTML is generated and take it from there.

Comment: The text are all there when I checked the source code.